# How can I create my own icon with propertise in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Maybe somebody knows the answer and try help me.

I am creating own button.

```xml
<fx:root maxHeight="100.0" maxWidth="100.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="80.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" type="StackPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="baseImage" fitHeight="66.0" fitWidth="72.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" StackPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER" />
      <Label fx:id="textBtn" alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="75.0" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP" StackPane.alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" />
   </children>
 </fx:root>
```

So I need to change my button (Image and Label), when I am creating this in FXML file.

```xml
<MyButton layoutX="200.0" layoutY="162.0" />
```

e.g

```xml
<MyButton layoutX="200.0" layoutY="162.0" image="" text="" />
```

Can somebody help me ?

My Java Code

```
public class MyButton extends StackPane
{


@FXML
private ImageView baseImage;

@FXML
private Label textBtn;

public MyButton()
{

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader =new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/pl/edu/wat/wcy/pz/icons/MyButtonView.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    init();

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } 
    catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}


public Label getTextBtn() {
    return textBtn;
}



public void setTextBtn(Label textBtn) {
    this.textBtn = textBtn;
}



public ImageView getBaseImage() {
    return baseImage;
}

public void setBaseImage(Image location) {
    this.baseImage.setImage(location);
}
public void setButton(Label textBtn, Image location){
    this.baseImage.setImage(location);
    this.textBtn = textBtn;
}
```

But I care about icon are changed in FXML file, not JavaCode

}

Comment: Can you show your Java code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set properties in FXML:

```
<MyButton layoutX="200.0" layoutY="162.0" image="" text="" />
```

you must define those properties in the corresponding class. In particular, `MyButton` must define `setImage(...)` and `setText(...)` methods (it already has `setLayoutX(...)` and `setLayoutY(...)` which are inherited from `StackPane`). It's hard to know exactly what functionality you want here, but you probably want to set these up as JavaFX Properties. If the intention is to map these into the `Label` and `ImageView` defined in the FXML file, you can just expose the relevant properties from the controls. You might need to work a bit to map the string from the image property into the correct thing.

```
public class MyButton extends StackPane
{


    @FXML
    private ImageView baseImage;

    @FXML
    private Label textBtn;

    public MyButton()
    {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader =new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/pl/edu/wat/wcy/pz/icons/MyButtonView.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);

        // not sure what this is:
        // init();
        // note that if you define 
        // public void initialize() {...} 
        // it will be called
        // automatically during the FXMLLoader.load() method

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } 
        catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public StringPropergty textProperty() {
        return textBtn.textProperty();
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    // similarly expose a property for image, but you need to be able to coerce it from a String

}
```

(Incidentally, I assume this is just an example for the purposes of understanding how to do this. Everything you have in the example can be done using a regular button. Just wanted to make that clear for any others reading this post.)